# Simple CRUD back-end for an inventory-tracking web API

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, crud

This is the simple back-end, albeit crude, that I made for a React Native mobile app project as a proof of concept. It's a basic CRUD for tracking supply inventory. The "shopping list" is items with a `Buy qty > 0`.

`selectData()` is a wrapper for a *SELECT* query using prepared statements:

- Signature: `selectData($columns, $table, $where, $fetchType)`
- `fetchType` is a *switch/case* to set the argument for `fetchAll()`.
- `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $table WHERE $where");`

It was easier for testing to use a remote MySQL database than to learn how to make/use a local database in React Native.

While I know that it works, does this even remotely count as a web API? How RESTful is it (or not)? Roast me if you must, but please explain it simply so I can learn.

After I created this, I started learning/using Laravel, but I haven't gotten into Laravel APIs yet.

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        include "initial.php"; //DB config, etc.

        if ($_GET['action'] === "getShoppingList") {
            echo json_encode(getShoppingList());
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] === "getSingleItem") {
            echo json_encode(getSingleItem($_GET['id']), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] === "getAllItems") {
            echo json_encode(getAllItems());
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] === "insert") {
            if (!isset($_GET['in_use'])) {
                echo json_encode(insertItem($_GET['itemName']));
            }
            else if (isset($_GET['in_use']) && isset($_GET['spare']) && isset($_GET['target'])) {
                echo json_encode(insertItem($_GET['itemName'], $_GET['in_use'], $_GET['spare'], $_GET['target']));
            }
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] === "update") {
            if (isset($_GET['field'])) {
                echo json_encode(updateSingleItemField($_GET['id'], $_GET['field'], $_GET['value']));
            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(updateItem($_GET['id'], $_GET['in_use'], $_GET['spare'], $_GET['target']));
            }
        }
        else if ($_GET['action'] === "delete") {
            echo json_encode(deleteItem($_GET['id']));
        }
    }

    function getShoppingList(){
        $items = selectData("id, item_name as name, in_use_quantity as 'in_use', spare_quantity as spare, target_quantity as target, CEILING(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity) as buy, updated", "items", "(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity > 0) ORDER BY item_name ASC", "obj");
        return $items;
    }

    function getSingleItem($id){
        $item = selectData("id, item_name as name, in_use_quantity as 'in_use', spare_quantity as spare, target_quantity as target, FORMAT(CEILING(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity),2) as buy, updated", "items", "id = $id", "obj");
        return $item;
    }

    function getAllItems(){
        $items = selectData("id, item_name as name, in_use_quantity as 'in_use', spare_quantity as spare, target_quantity as target, FORMAT(CEILING(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity),2) as buy, updated", "items", "1 ORDER BY item_name ASC", "obj");
        return $items;
    }

    function insertItem($itemName, $inUseQuantity=0, $spareQuantity=0, $targetQuantity=0){
        $conn = loadDatabase();
        $query = "INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `item_name`, `in_use_quantity`, `spare_quantity`, `target_quantity`, `updated`) VALUES (NULL, '$itemName', '$inUseQuantity', '$spareQuantity', '$targetQuantity', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        $conn = null;
        return $id;
    }

    function updateSingleItemField($id, $field, $value){
        $conn = loadDatabase();
        $fieldName = $field . "_quantity";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `items` SET `$fieldName` = $value WHERE `items`.`id` = $id");
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn = null;
        return $stmt->rowCount(); //returns TRUE if it was successful or FALSE if it failed
    }

    function updateItem($id, $inUseQuantity=0, $spareQuantity=0, $targetQuantity=0){
        $conn = loadDatabase();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `items` SET `in_use_quantity` = $inUseQuantity, `spare_quantity` = $spareQuantity, `target_quantity` = $targetQuantity WHERE `items`.`id` = $id");
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn = null;
        return $stmt->rowCount(); //returns TRUE if it was successful or FALSE if it failed
    }

    function deleteItem($id){
        $conn = loadDatabase();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`id` = $id");
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn = null;
//returns TRUE if it was successful or FALSE if it failed
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
```

Comment: Just a personal style comment: I would rather use a `switch` if you've got no other criteria than the content of a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: there will be a lot of links to my own site because I am helping people with PHP for 20+ years and got an obsession with writing articles about most common issues.

I don't know much about restful stuff or whether it does matter, but there are many other areas of improvement. Let's review some of them

#### The selectData() function

First of all, the `selectData()` function is a wrapper for a SELECT query using [*cargo cult* prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) which makes it essentially **insecure**. It's a placeholder that makes your prepared query secure, not just a magical call to prepare().

Another thing is that [gibberish `selectData()` syntax](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#select). Honestly, what are you trying to bargain here for? Spare yourself typing a few SQL keywords, seriously? Making it gibberish out of a precious almost-natural-English sentence, convenient and compatible? 
Look, you are already abusing the `$where` parameter by weird `"1 ORDER BY item_name ASC"` statement. Last but not least: such a syntax makes it harder to use prepared statements.
Come on. Let's keep it SQL.

Also, it seems that `selectData()` connects every time of it's own. Although it is not a problem for a primitive atomic API that always perform just a single SQL query per HTTP request, *no API would remain thus*. It will grow up to perform many queries per request and having each query to connect of its own will become a problem. Your script should always create just a single connection per single HTTP request and use it for all queries. So create a $conn variable as shown [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) and then use it for all database interactions in your code.

Also, I suppose that `selectData()` always returns a simple 2-dimensional list, which severely cripples the [PDO's great ability to return the requested data in many different formats](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn). So, instead make this function to return a PDO statement from which you'll be able to get the resulting data. So it will work as a sort of that "obj" thingy, but in a much more versatile way.

Given all the above, create a [PDO helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function) like this:

```
function pdo($pdo, $sql, $args = NULL)
{
    if (!$args)
    {
         return $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

So it keeps the SQL syntax intact yet makes all your queries *safe* and result sets versatile.

Let's rewrite some your functions to this new format

```
function getShoppingList($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT id, item_name as name, in_use_quantity as 'in_use',
               spare_quantity as spare, target_quantity as target, 
               CEILING(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity) as buy, 
               updated 
            FROM items 
            WHERE target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity > 0
            ORDER BY item_name ASC";
    return pdo($conn, $sql)->fetchAll();
}

function getSingleItem($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, item_name as name, in_use_quantity as 'in_use', 
              spare_quantity as spare, target_quantity as target,
              FORMAT(CEILING(target_quantity - in_use_quantity - spare_quantity),2)
              as buy, updated 
           FROM items
           WHERE id = ?";
    return pdo($conn, $sql, $id)->fetch();
}

function insertItem($conn, $itemName, $inUseQuantity=0, $spareQuantity=0, $targetQuantity=0){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `items` 
            (`id`, `item_name`, `in_use_quantity`, `spare_quantity`, `target_quantity`, `updated`) 
            VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
    pdo($conn, $sql, [$itemName, $inUseQuantity, $spareQuantity, $targetQuantity]);
    return  $conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

a couple notes:

- `getSingleItem()` returns a *single item*, not a multidimensional array
- although you can designate the row format as a parameter in `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`, it would be most convenient to set up the default fetch mode in the beginning. So you would only define it explicitly in case you will need some different format. Therefore n need for that ever-present "obj" parameter.
- notice the brand new `insertItem()`. Neat, eh?
- all your queries are **secure** now

Now you can rewrite all other functions to this format.

#### The router part

There are some repetitions in the router part that could be optimized

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
     case "getShoppingList":
        $response = getShoppingList();
        break;

    case "getSingleItem":
        $response = getSingleItem($_GET['id']);
        break;

    case "getAllItems":
        $response = getAllItems();
        break;

    case "insert":
        if (!isset($_GET['in_use'])) {
            $response = insertItem($_GET['itemName']);
        } elseif (isset($_GET['spare'], $_GET['target'])) {
            $response = insertItem(
                $_GET['itemName'], $_GET['in_use'], $_GET['spare'], $_GET['target']
            );
        }

    case "update":
        if (isset($_GET['field'])) {
            $response = updateSingleItemField($_GET['id'], $_GET['field'], $_GET['value']));
        } else {
            $response = updateItem(
                $_GET['id'], $_GET['in_use'], $_GET['spare'], $_GET['target']
            );
        }

    case "delete":
        $response = deleteItem($_GET['id']);

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

#### The code formatting

In your question, one has to scroll A LOT to read the code. And in my answer you have all the code visible. Please do not torture yourself or anyone else by making that awhul horizontal scrollbar.